# How to Enable and Disable submit button using text box value

Tags: javascript, html, addition

(This text box value comes dynamically)

If textbox gets value 100 it will enable submit button but here enable submit button after editing the value to 100 without changing it won't enable.

```
<script>
    function manage(txt) {
    var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
    if (txt.value != '100') {
        bt.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        bt.disabled = false;
    }
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)"/>
   
<input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled />

Comment: Your question is not clear.... please re-word it.....

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653134/how-to-enable-and-disable-submit-button-using-text-box-value/51653601#51653601) @SatheeshChowdary for a quick way to achieve the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser. To make sure that works, use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and removeAttribute

```
var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
bt.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
bt.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

```js
function manage(txt) {
  var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
  if (txt.value != '100') {
    console.log('Disabled');
    bt.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  } else {
    console.log('Enabled');
    bt.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="manage(this)" />
<input type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Not absolutely sure what the problem is here since your example is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve), but you can use the `"keyup"` event to listen to any changes made to your `input` element while typing.

Also, your code is unnecessarily verbose:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
   /* Disable the button, if the value of the input is <> 100. */
   document.getElementById("btSubmit").disabled = (this.value != 100);
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input type = "text" id = "txt"/>
<input type = "submit" id = "btSubmit" disabled/>
```

If you prefer using inline JavaScript in your HTML code, the above solution can be written as:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function manage (element) {
   /* Disable the button, if the value of the input is <> 100. */
   document.getElementById("btSubmit").disabled = (element.value != 100);
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input type = "text" id = "txt" onkeyup = "manage(this)"/>
<input type = "submit" id = "btSubmit" disabled/>
```

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment, so that I can address your objection and improve this answer.